# Pi3 stuck on rainbow screen after a kernel downgrade

Tags: raspbian, boot, kernel, retropie, rpi-update

I've a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian with the kernel 4.4.38-v7+. I want to downgrade to version 4.1.X to have full support for xboxdrv.

I used the script *rpi-update*:

`apt install -y rpi-update
rpi-update ddacb5e91eb5c67bb39df99182b071d7199e7a74`

After that I got the rainbow screen. I tried with the [boot_delay=1](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen) but didn't work.

There is an specific kernel release to use with Pi3? or Did I forget an step? The power supply provides 20 W. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have broken your installation. `rpi-update` can install different kernels, although it is definitely **NOT** a beginner tool.

There are many changes in the latest Raspbian, which are dependent on the 4.4. kernels, so this is unlikely to be usable.

If you **REALLY** need an old version of the OS, I suggest you restore from a backup, or do a clean installation using one of the releases in http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/